# Mostrar div si no se cumple condición

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente proyecto: https://jsfiddle.net/mdomfu/3qbmLwtz/3/

En él se filtra la tabla según la selección del checkbox. Me gustaría que, si no se encuentran resultados que coincidan con el filtro se oculte la tabla entera (incluido el header) y además se muestre el div no-results.

Gracias adelantadas.

Comment: Te hace falta estas líneas en el **else** showDiv(); $('.table').hide(); Para mostrar el div y ocultar la tabla.

Comment: Estimado, por favor no utilices enlaces externos para mostrar tu código, el módulo de preguntas tiene para poder agregar el código que necesitas acá. Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder ayudarte

Comment: Disculpa, soy nuevo por aquí. Lo tendré en cuenta para próximas!

Answer (score 0):

Te faltarían éstas líneas en el código de tu JS:

```
function filterTable() {
    var filter_selector = '';
    $('.filter :checked').each(function() {
        filter_selector += '[' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + '"' + $(this).val() + '"]';
    });

    if (filter_selector.length < 1) {
        tableRows.show();
        hideDiv(); //Ocultar el Div
        $('.table').show(); //Mostrar la tabla
    } else {
        tableRows.hide().filter(filter_selector).show();
        showDiv(); //Mostrar el Div
        $('.table').hide(); //Ocultar la tabla
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero con este código me lo oculta siempre. Si hay resultados oculta la tabla, y si no hay, también.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
  <div class="filter">
<div class="column">
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="masc">Masculí</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="fem">Femení</input>
</div>
<div class="column">
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="pc">Pista coberta</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="al">Aire lliure</input>
</div>
<div class="column">
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub8">Sub.8</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub10">Sub.10</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub12">Sub.12</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub14">Sub.14</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub16">Sub.16</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub18">Sub.18</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub20">Sub.20</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="sub23">Sub.23</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="abs">Absolut</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" value="mst">Màster</input>
</div>
</div>
<div class="table">
<table>
<thead>
<th>PROVA</th>
<th>ATLETA</th>
<th>CLUB</th>
<th>MARCA</th>
<th>LOCALITAT</th>
<th>DATA</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>60m.ll.</td>
<td>Felipe Vivancos Ruiz</td>
<td>C.A. Pitius</td>
<td>6.79</td>
<td>Sevilla</td>
<td>22/02/2003</td>
</tr>   
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>60m.ll.</td>
<td>Guillermo Vidal Bauzá</td>
<td>F.C. Barcelona</td>
<td>6.79</td>
<td>Madrid</td>
<td>15/01/2005</td>
</tr>  
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>200m.ll.</td>
<td>Sebastià Pons Triay</td>
<td>Cecome Sant Lluis</td>
<td>21.97</td>
<td>Madrid</td>
<td>02/03/2019</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>400m.ll.</td>
<td>Benjamín González Goméz</td>
<td>Mediterráneo</td>
<td>47.2-</td>
<td>San Sebastián</td>
<td>23/01/1982</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>800m.ll.</td>
<td>David Bustos González</td>
<td>ADA Calvià</td>
<td>1:47.05</td>
<td>Doha</td>
<td>13/03/2010</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>1500m.ll.</td>
<td>Mateo Cañellas Martorell</td>
<td>*</td>
<td>3:37.99</td>
<td>Sevilla</td>
<td>17/02/1995</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>3000m.ll.</td>
<td>David Palacio Martín</td>
<td>Fent Camí Mislata</td>
<td>7:54.33</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>18/01/2019</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>60m.t.</td>
<td>Felipe Vivancos Ruiz</td>
<td>C.A. Pitius</td>
<td>7.56</td>
<td>Paris</td>
<td>04/03/2011</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Alçada</td>
<td>Antoni J. Albertí Amengual</td>
<td>*</td>
<td>1.95</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>11/02/1990</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Perxa</td>
<td>Santiago Bañón Cliville</td>
<td>ECM Menorca Atl.</td>
<td>5.31</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>22/02/2004</td>
</tr> 
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Llargada</td>
<td>Jaume Comas Castro</td>
<td>C.A. Pitius</td>
<td>7.54</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>18/02/2006</td>
</tr>
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Triple Salt</td>
<td>José Juan Hernández Redondo</td>
<td>EAMJ-Playas Jandía</td>
<td>15.15</td>
<td>San Sebastián</td>
<td>01/03/2009</td>
</tr>
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Pes</td>
<td>José Angel Pinedo Ordinas</td>
<td>Fent Camí Mislata</td>
<td>18.59</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>17/02/2018</td>
</tr>
<tr gender="masc" type="pc" cat="abs">
<td>Heptatló</td>
<td>Antoni J. Albertí Amengual</td>
<td>*</td>
<td>4.652</td>
<td>Valencia</td>
<td>11/02/1990</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="no-results" style="display: none;">
No s'han trobat persones que coincideixin amb el primer cognom que has seleccionat. Si creus que és un error,
<span style="font-size: 15px; color: Grey;">
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</span><a href="mailto:llicencies@faib.es?subject=❗ Sense dades o dades errònies a la web de la FAIB-llicències">
contacta amb nosaltres.
</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function filterTable() {
    var filter_selector = '';
    $('.filter :checked').each(function() {
        filter_selector += '[' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + '"' + $(this).val() + '"]';
    });

    if (filter_selector.length < 1) {
        tableRows.show();
        hideDiv(); //Ocultar el Div
        $('.table').show(); //Mostrar la tabla
    } else {
        tableRows.hide().filter(filter_selector).show();
        showDiv(); //Mostrar el Div
        $('.table').hide(); //Ocultar la tabla
    }
}
```

Con este JS la tabla se oculta siempre, coincidan o no los filtros de los checkboxes. Me gustaría que únicamente se mostrara el *div id="no-results"* si no hay resultados cuando el usuario filtra mediante los checkboxes.